# I am trying to add some code to an existing code

Tags: express

I am a beginner to Express app and I am trying to add my name and date into the following code underneath of 'Hello World' in a `localhost 3000`, but it does not work. What to do?

```
const express = require ('express')
const app = express()

app.get ('/', (req, res) => res.send ('Hello World!'),

app.listen (3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

Comment: If any answers to your questions helps/solves the issue, you can mark them as accepted. You haven't accepted any of the previous answers to your question as well

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is typo or what but your code is missing corresponding closing bracket on `app.get(...`  line.

You can do it just by adding whatever you want to display inside `res.send()`. The following code will display your name along with date below it-

```
const express = require ('express')
const app = express();

const date = new Date().toDateString();
const getNameAndDate = () => `<h1>My name is Hass!</h1>${date}`

app.get ('/', (req, res) => res.send ('hello World'+ getNameAndDate()));

app.listen (3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

You can even send a file instead of sending it like this. You can create an `index.html` file and write however you want your page to be displayed. Then just replace above with -

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('public/index.html');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! How about adding name and date function that shows current date and keeping the "Hello World", I mean two strings and a date function in separate lines?

Comment: @Hass You could just keep the Hello world and then add whatever you want to display after that. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, but how to add date there?

Comment: @Hass Check my edit above. The output you will get would be this - https://HummingSparklingQuadrant--five-nine.repl.co

Comment: Thank you! I added my name and the date as new Date() at the end as you said, and it worked. How to remove my name to the next line in "res.send"? It prints "hello Worls" and my name in the same line.

Comment: @Hass Just put Hello world and you name in separate `h1` tags or you could even just add  `<br />` to move to the next line